# How to do safety mirroring innodb table on mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have one Mysql InnoDb table with rush trafik on row update. The table is also frequently used for heavy select query (especially group by for summary report).  As I know this heavy select query will interfere or reduce the update peformance. So i have an idea to mirror this table, so the heavy select query will do in this mirror table (delay 15 menit still accepted).

Fyi, this table have size approximately 10 GB, I have used mysql event (scheduled every 15 minute) to copy this table to another with "insert into select" query. Actually it need more than 60 second for copy process, but the update query still impacted when this event running.

So Is there any best/common practise for mirroring table mysql with minimum impact to currently query (especially update) process on the master table?

Note : I want to do on the same server

Comment: Use the built-in replication mechanism

Comment: Are you talking about mirroring on the same server? Replication is for multiple servers.

Comment: Yes, I want to do on the same server.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a simple method for mirroring tables. [dba.se] is the place to ask about server configuration.

Comment: If you mirror the table to the same harddrive, then the selects and the modifications will still battle for the same common resource: the harddrive. The standard solution for this is what @Barmar suggested: set up another server and use replication and use some kind of a liad balancer to direct the updates toward one server and selects to another. Setting all these up is not a programming question, but a database admin one, so I also vote to move this question over to the dba sister site.

Comment: @Shadow I think he's more concerned about table locking than physical resources.

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible. But the question does not contain this detail.

Comment: Why do you assume your select statement will interfere with updates? SELECTS are non-blocking and aquire no locks apart from a metadata lock preventing table structure modification. Have you measured a performance drop in inserts/updates while running a select?

Comment: With InnoDB, as long as your active set fits into the buffer pool completely, you should notice no real difference at all, unless some rows are updated multiple times while the select is running.

If it is a really long running select, then you would have the problem that your UNDO log will grow as the purge thread(s) can only clean up UNDO records again once that SELECT finished. But that would be the same problem with a mirror table on the same server.

So if there's a real load problem with this, then replicating the table to an extra reporting slave is the only way to go ...

Comment: @danblack When the copying table is running I always find many update query more than 3 seconds in that table (show processlist), while it doesn't otherwise.

Comment: If your copying a table, you may be filling up the innodb log buffer. What I'm talking about is not bothering copying at all. Let SELECT continue (mostly)locklessly and have the minimal number of updates continue. Measure the performance of these updates. Read @HartmutHolzgraefe's comment. He's been doing this much longer than me.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Speed up the Summary by building and maintaining a Summary Table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables .  In particular, this is likely to segregate the summary select, which will now touch only the summary table, from the updates.  And it will

Plan B:  Use replication on the *same* server.  Be sure to have a different "Port" (such as 3307) for that Replica.  Direct summary requests to that port.  Continue to direct writes to the Primary (your current instance).

Plan C:  If the "update" is just a "Likes" or "Visits" counter, then do the following to avoid some of the interference.  Move that column to a separate table.  The two tables would have the same `PRIMARY KEY` for ease of `JOINing`.  The update will avoid interfering with any selects that don't need also need to counter.

Plan D:  Plans A,B,C are independent; do a combination of them.

The repeated copying of the table will (I predict) be poor for both maintenance and performance.